# C++ LNK2001 : unresolved external symbol when adding windows phone runtime component

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

This is probably a duplicate question but as far as I searched I couldn't find the problem. 
The error returned is a problem of the dependencies but I don't understand what is actually wrong. So I have a Windows Phone project, I added a Windows Phone runtime component project,
I created a class and 2 public functions in my .header :

```
 public ref class Base64Encoding sealed
{
public:
    String^ EncodeData(String^ StringData);
    String^ DecodeString(String^ StringData);
};
```

And in my `.cpp` I populated the functions

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Base64Encode.h"
#include <wchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
String^ EncodeData(String^ StringData)
  {
    .
    .
    .
    .
     // return the result
        return StringFromAscIIChars(result);

    }
String^ DecodeString(String^ StringData)
    {    
    .
    .
    .
      return StringFromAscIIChars(result);
    }
```

And when i try to build 2 errors of type LNK2001 return as follows:

```
Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual
class Platform::String ^ __cdecl
Base64Encode_::Base64Encoding::[Base64Encode_::__IBase64EncodingPublicNonVirtuals]::EncodeData(class
Platform::String ^)"
(?EncodeData@?Q__IBase64EncodingPublicNonVirtuals@Base64Encode_@@Base64Encoding@2@U$AAAP$AAVString@Platform@@P$AAV45@@Z)    C:\Users\CodeNinja\Documents\Visual
Studio
2013\Projects\OpenscapeWP\Base64Encode\Base64Encode.obj Base64Encode

Error 2 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual
class Platform::String ^ __cdecl
Base64Encode_::Base64Encoding::[Base64Encode_::__IBase64EncodingPublicNonVirtuals]::DecodeString(class
Platform::String ^)"
(?DecodeString@?Q__IBase64EncodingPublicNonVirtuals@Base64Encode_@@Base64Encoding@2@U$AAAP$AAVString@Platform@@P$AAV45@@Z)  C:\Users\CodeNinja\Documents\Visual
Studio
2013\Projects\OpenscapeWP\Base64Encode\Base64Encode.obj Base64Encode
```

If I remove the public keyword in the .header for both functions the linker issue is gone but the functions are inaccessible.

In the header I got a static function to translate from ASCII to chars but I think this is hardly the issue. So what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue and i am leaving the answer here even if i am answering my own question, for someone else. I have created two global functions in my .cpp file.  They need to be class members:

```
String^ Base64Encoding::EncodeData(String^ StringData)
{ ... }

String^ Base64Encoding::DecodeString(String^ StringData)
{ ... }
```